# Changing the api endpoint to my thingsboard app

Tags: flutter, api, dart, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I'm still new to thingsboard app, flutter and dart. Right now I have my thingsboard which have it's own database (it is managed by someone else). I want the thingsboard app to pointed to my thingsboard instead of the demo one. I change the thingsboardApiEndpoint by replacing https://demo.thingsboard.io/ to https://gateway.myiotplatform.com/ in app_constant.dart file but the emulator would take forever to load.

Can someone help me regarding this issue? I try to find the api keyword in the source code but nothing are available. Really have no idea what to do.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You are doing it correctly. But the endpoint >>> https://gateway.myiotplatform.com/  is not working(checked in postman), that's why the emulator is taking so long. Ask someone who is working on the server side to fix it.

Comment: What should I say to the person? I wonder what should I check in postman? I try to post to api/auth/login and the response header  showed me token and refreshToken. So i wonder what goes wrong.